# Kusto ML plugins - CPU/Disk costs show 0

Tags: azure-data-explorer

Queries that use KustoML plugins (e.g. autocluster/diffpatterns) take a while to run, but the CPU/Disk stats don't reflect this - they show 0.

Thus these queries don't show up in any analysis done to see what's using the most resources on a cluster, and also doesn't give the right feedback to users on the cost of these queries.